# What's wrong with this simple XML?

Tags: xml

I can't understand why this xml below cannot be parsed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dumb [ 
<!ENTITY % param "<!ENTITY wrap 'WRAPPER'>">
%param;
]>
<test>&wrap;</test>
```

Xml below is also not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dumb [ 
<!ENTITY % param "DEADBEEF">
<!ENTITY normal "%param;">
]>
<test>&normal;</test>
```

However, if I don't use DTD parameter Entity, no problem accurs as xml below is showing that example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dumb [ 
<!ENTITY normal "param">
]>
<test>&normal;</test>
```

I just want to test and practice to use DTD parameter ENTITY.
Did I made mistakes while using DTD parameter ENTITY?

Also, is there any platform of framework where I can debug my xml during write-up step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dumb [ 
<!ENTITY % param "DEADBEEF">
<!ENTITY normal "%param;">
]>
<test>&normal;</test>
```

I get a clear error message

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
> 4; columnNumber: 25; The parameter entity reference "%param;" cannot
> occur within markup in the internal subset of the DTD.

That is due to https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wfc-PEinInternalSubset requiring

> In the internal DTD subset, parameter-entity references must not occur
> within markup declarations; they may occur where markup declarations
> can occur.

In both examples I think the DOCTYPE name should match the root element name, i.e. use `DOCTYPE test` and `<test>..</test>`.

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with the first sample.

Which XML parser did you use, which error message(s) exactly did you get?

Comment: Thank you for kind answer. It's really helpful. Actually, I use some website parser to test my xml. Can you recommand any tools for looking such errors and result?

Comment: Any XML parser with good DTD supports like Xerces will do, it might all depend on the platform and the tools (e.g. command line or GUI) you want to use. Most XML editors or XML editor plugins for code or text editors should help.